# Querying jsonb field with multiple values in postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a table with a JSONB column which stores some structure as below:

`[{
    "id": "id1",
    "value": "value1"
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "value": "value2"
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "value": "value3"
  }]`

I want to query the jsonb field by providing more than one values for the "value" field like in a OR condition.

Currently i have the query running for a single value in the where clause and i have to run it in a loop from the persistence layer and then merge the results.
This is what i am using:

```
select * 
from table1 
where lower(column1::text)::jsonb @> cast(lower('[{"value":"value1"}]'::text) AS JSONB)
```

Is there a way i can pass multiple values and the result will be an OR for more than one values passed.

Comment: Today I answered something like that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772005/postgresql-get-parent-categories-from-table/49782552#49782552](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772005/postgresql-get-parent-categories-from-table/49782552#49782552) Perhaps you can use something like that.

Comment: Anyway, it would be great if you add to your question the Output you are looking for or an example of what you are trying to achieve